# iPhone 6 only charging when powered off

Tags: iphone, hardware, battery

My iPhone was only charging when turned off whether I used an original cable or not.

Today it stopped charging even when it is powered off.

Can a battery replacement fix this? If not, what else could be the issue?

Comment: If your phone stopped charging, it could be the battery or it could be the charging circuitry.  You need to get it serviced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent my iPhone to assistance and them have the answer: The problem is in [the power management IC](http://cellphonerepairtutorials.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/what-is-power-mangement-ic-how-does-it.html)